# Why there is a difference between quote.getTotals() and totals.totals()

Tags: checkout, javascript

```
define([
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache'
], function (ko, Component, quote, priceUtils, totals, totalProcessor, cartCache) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** some logic **/
        shippingAddressObserver: function (address) {
            cartCache.clear('totals');
            totalProcessor.estimateTotals(address);
            console.log(quote.getTotals(), totals.totals());
            /** @todo check why the extra fee is not displayed on the first shot **/
            let extraFree = totals.getSegment('extraFree');
            if (extraFree !== null) {
                this.price(extraFree.value);
                this.title(extraFree.title);
            } else {
                this.price(0);
                this.title('');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[image: result in console]

Answer (score 2):

It looks that it comes from a time lag between the data retrieved from the server and what is in local storage.

To get accurate information from server about the totals, you can do :

```
...
    totals.totals.subscribe(this.totalModificationObserver.bind(this));
...
totalModificationObserver: function (totals) {
    let extraFee = ko.utils.arrayFirst(totals.total_segments, function(total) {
         return total.code == 'extrafee';
    });
    if (typeof extraFee !== 'undefined' && extraFee !== null) {
         this.price(extraFee.value);
         this.title(extraFee.title);
    } else {
         this.price(0);
         this.title('');
    }
}
```

That way, the latest information is available.